# Не копирует файлы volume docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose

После того, как указываю в docker-compose.yml опцию volume - он создает папки в контейнере, но не файлы.
Как ни пытался - все впустую (менял пути, открывал доступ).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Windows 10 1607
Volume также не создаются.

Client:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:15:28 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.0
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   8eab29e
 Built:        Thu Jul 28 21:15:28 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Comment: *If you are using Docker Machine on Mac or Windows, your Docker daemon has only limited access to your OS X or Windows filesystem. Docker Machine tries to auto-share your /Users (OS X) or C:\Users (Windows) directory.* - похоже, сработает только при физическом нахождении volume внутри домашней директории.

Answer (score 0):

Что бы docker смог подключать тома данных из произвольных папок в системе Windows должен стоять пароль.